# Encode special characters in ajax form (asp mvc)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax form created with the html helper: `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...))`

The problem is when I post some characters like ñ, €, etc they are encoded as ñ -> Ã±, €-> â¬ when they are received by the controller.

I already have this section in my Web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" fileEncoding="iso-8859-15" requestEncoding="iso-8859-15" responseEncoding="iso-8859-15" />
```

which solved previous encoding problems when passing special characters in urls.

How can I get this problem fixed so I can receive that characters in my controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your controller code please. What is your parameter type for the controller method What does the request look like when you observe it through fiddler ?

Comment: I wonder if this could be due to the default JavaScriptSerializer. What happens if you send the same data after serializing it with Json.NET instead? I hear the RTM version of MVC4 is going to use Json.NET out of the box: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that AJAX uses the `UTF-8` encoding when it sends the request. But you have configured your server to expect `requestEncoding="iso-8859-15"` which is where the discrepancy comes from.

Let's suppose that you have an input field named `Category` in your form and the user enters the `ñ` character in it. If you use a normal `Html.BeginForm` the following POST request payload will be sent to the server:

```
Category=%F1
```

On the other hand if you use an `Ajax.BeginForm`, the following request POST payload will be sent to the server:

```
Category=%C3%B1&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

In this case the server is not capable of properly decoding this UTF-8 encoded request because it expects requests to be `iso-8859-15` encoded.

So you could modify your web.config to use UTF-8 request and response encoding for your site. Can't think of a valid reason in 2012 to use any other encoding than UTF-8 in a web application.

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" 
    uiCulture="auto" 
    culture="auto" 
    fileEncoding="utf-8" 
    requestEncoding="utf-8" 
    responseEncoding="utf-8" 
/>
```

Also don't forget to update any `<meta>` tags that you might have in your layouts in order to use `UTF-8` as well:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem and I understood why it didn't work that way. The problem now, is when I type something like 'ñ' in my search box, so it redirects to the search page like this: www.asdf.com/search?input=%F1, so in that page, the character %F1 can't be decoded properly. Should I encode it before passing it to the url? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I was using the javascript function 'escape' so the user can search for '&' for example. I removed that function and now special characters are passed correctly through urls. Now i guess I have to manually replace '&' for its corresponding encoded value.